# Black background on file icon

Tags: c#, html

I have a program for searching files on a PC, I think it makes no sense to show all the code, because the problem is different.
I'm trying to display the file icon via javascript and html (using CefSharp). Everything works fine, the icon is displayed, but ... Why is it displayed with a black background? On the file itself, it is transparent, but when output to `base64` it becomes with a black background. Is it possible to fix this?
Get bytes func:

```
private byte[] GetBytes(Icon icon)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    icon.Save(ms);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Icon from file path func:

```
public static Icon IconFromFilePath(string filePath)
{
    var result = (Icon)null;

    try
    {
        result = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath);
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
    }

    return result;
}
```

Icon bytes to Base64:

```
var theIcon = IconFromFilePath(f.FullName); //f.FullName - full path to file
byte[] imageArray = GetBytes(theIcon);
string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
```

Test icon:

```html
<img src="data:image/x-icon;base64,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" width="100">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public static Icon IconFromFilePath(string filePath)
{
    var result = (Icon)null;

    try
    {
        result = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath);
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
    }

    return result;
}

public Bitmap FromIconToBitmap(Icon icon)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(icon.Width, icon.Height);
    using (Graphics gp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gp.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        gp.DrawIcon(icon, new Rectangle(0, 0, icon.Width, icon.Height));
    }
    return bmp;
}

public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

Usage:

```
var theIcon = IconFromFilePath(f.FullName); //f.FullName - full path to file
byte[] imageArray = ImageToByte(FromIconToBitmap(theIcon));
string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
```